# Spring Boot autowire configuration class into Junit Test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test

I currently run into a problem with Junit testing in Spring Boot. I have an `@Configuration` class for which I want to test the `@Bean` methods. Because these methods are skipped during tests, I extracted the content of the configuration method to a protected method which will then be called inside the `@Bean` method of the `@Configuration` class.
I did that so I can test the behaviour of the methods. Inside this method different `@ConfigurationProperties` are used to load some setups.

Now, in my `ConfigurationTest` class, I am mocking the `ConfigurationProperties` classes so I can test the correct behaviour of the `@Bean` method.

My problem is, that my Mockito mocks of the `ConfigurationProperties` classes always return null, when I am inside the `@Bean` method (more specifically inside the protected method that is called from the @Bean method). It feels like there is a problem with how I setup the `@Configuration` class. Currently I am autowiring it.

My question now is, how do I setup the `@Configuration` class correctly, so I can call its functions and mock the return values of the there used `@ConfigurationProperties` classes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of asserts do you want to run on this @Configuration class under test ?

Comment: Overall, nobody tests configuration beans like this. You test it indirectly by testing the individual beans it creates together or separately. You just use @Autowired on the beans you want to inject into your test and this is how you know if Configuration had created them OK or not

Comment: If you can show some code, it would be easier to help you, and understand.

Answer (score -1):

Add `@EnableConfigurationProperties(value=YourConfigurationProperties.class)` to your test class. This will load the properties.